# Do NSURL security-scoped bookmarks remain valid after a user moves a file?

Tags: cocoa, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, sandbox

After obtaining a security scoped bookmark to a file, I am seeing mixed results with the bookmark after a user moves the file associated with the bookmark to a different location.

**What I am seeing:**

- If the user moves the file, the bookmark resolves correctly to the
  new location. However, once moved, if the user makes a change and
  saves, the bookmark does not resolve and gives an error that the
  file does not exist.
- If the user makes changes to the file and
  saves, the bookmark resolves correctly. If the user moves the file
  after they save, the bookmark no longer resolves and gives an error
  that the file doesn't exist.

Based on what I am seeing, it makes me think bookmarks don't work they way I think they do under sandboxing. However, I have played with a few other sandbox apps and they seem to handle it fine.

**UPDATE:**

- The URL is to a document for my app.
- All of the modify/saving that happens all goes through the normal NSDocument plumbing.

Comment: If it's an `NSDocument` for your own app, why do you have a bookmark to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, security scoped-bookmarks do remain valid after a user moves a file.

After some experimenting, it seems to take the OS a small amount of time to update whatever resource it uses to help with resolving bookmarks. It seems that I was resolving bookmarks too soon after moving the files associated with them.